# How to detect firebase user registration and signIn successfully in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/) of FlutterFire, there are two different methods for signIn and signUp for email and password authentication.

For signUp

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

For signIn

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

By this code I can handle error by `FirebaseAuthException` and stop some loading progress. But how do I detect that user successfully register and do something as per success registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how do I detect that user successfully register?

It is actually detailed [in the documentation section that explains](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#emailpassword-registration--sign-in) the code you mention in your question.

In particular, for registration the [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#registration) says:

> The method is a **two-step operation**; it will first create the new
> account (if it does not already exist and the password is valid) and
> **then automatically sign in the user in to that account**. If you are listening to changes in authentication state, **a new event will be
> sent to your listeners**.

To listen to changes in authentication state you can call the [`authStateChanges()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html) method on your `FirebaseAuth` instance, as follows:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      // !!!!! Here you know the user is signed-in !!!!!
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

---

For signIn, it is the same. The [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#sign-in) states that:

> Once successful, if you are listening to changes in authentication
> state, a new event will be sent to your listeners.

Refer to the registration case above.

---

So, in summary, on one hand you call the methods to either register (`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`) or sign-in (`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`) and, on the other hand, you set a listener that listens to changes in authentication state. The listener alerts you when the call to one of the two methods is successful.

The `on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {...}` blocks deals with the cases when the call to one of the two methods is not successful.

---

Finally, note the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/dive-into-firebase-auth-on-flutter-email-and-link-sign-in-e51603eb08f8) from the *Firebase Developers* Medium publication: it presents a slightly different approach, declaring `async` methods which check if the `user` object returned by the methods is `null` or not, and call `setState()` accordingly.

For example:

```
void _register() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = (await 
      _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      )
  ).user;
  if (user != null) {
    setState(() {
      _success = true;
      _userEmail = user.email;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _success = true;
    });
  }
}
```